# How to test log rolling and deletion in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using below configuration taken from [Elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html). Instead of waiting for 7D or a day, how can I test this immediately?

Below is my log4j2.properties file

```
...
appender.deprecation_rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.deprecation_rolling.name = deprecation_rolling
appender.deprecation_rolling.fileName = ${sys:es.logs}_deprecation.log
appender.deprecation_rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.deprecation_rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.10000m%n
appender.deprecation_rolling.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs}_deprecation-%i.log.gz
appender.deprecation_rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.deprecation_rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.deprecation_rolling.policies.size.size = 1GB
appender.deprecation_rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.deprecation_rolling.strategy.max = 4

logger.deprecation.name = org.elasticsearch.deprecation
logger.deprecation.level = warn
logger.deprecation.appenderRef.deprecation_rolling.ref = deprecation_rolling
logger.deprecation.additivity = false
...

appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.age = 1D
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*
```

Note: I am using elasticsearch 5.0.1

**Update**: I do not want to wait for a day `1D` to test if the log files are being deleted or not. How can I test with 10 minute or so to test this scenario? Something like rolling happens every 1 minute and deletion happens for logs older than 10 minutes.

Comment: add more detail. what do you mean by "nstead of waiting for 7D or a day, how can I test this immediately?"

Comment: @DaniyalSyed: Is there any property which allows me to test log rolling and deletion immediately? Something like rolling happens every 1 minute and deletion happens for logs older than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way.

Actually, I use a size triggering policy to force or cause a Deletion policy and so test if my log4j2.properties works or not.

This an example of our log4j2.properties file, I highlight in black the change.

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.-10000m%n
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
**appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 100KB**
```

And then, I change Debug Logging Level on ElasticSearch.

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{"transient":{"logger._root":"DEBUG"}}
```

In that way, I'm causing many logs and triggering the RollingFile Appender with its regarding actions.

So, you can check quickly your log4j2.properties file without to wait 24h.

When you want to stop your test, you must set the default value:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{"transient":{"logger._root":"ERROR"}}
```

Regards